# Looking for a rigorous treatment about Laplace transform.

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, integral-transforms

I am looking for a book that deal with integral transforms in a very rigorous way, Fourier analysis I discover that functional analysis and Lebesgue Integral books cover the Fourier analysis( With a little piece of abstract algebra ) in a nicely way but I didn´t found nothing similar to this even in complex analysis books about Laplace transfom. I´ll be greatful if somebody know somo good references.

Comment: The Laplace/Mellin transform is a major topic of the theory of $\zeta(s)$ and more generally of complex analysis, a tangential field is distribution theory (and functional analysis).

Answer (score 0):

You can check:

1. Debnat Integral transforms and their applications.CRC Press
2. Davies Integral transforms and their applications. Springer GTM